# Making changes on a different property of recursive function

Tags: php

I'm currently developing this code that traverse a hierarchical array which should compute the sub-total of a property called cur_compensation. My issue is that the changes I do is not getting save

```
  private function computeSubTotal($hierarchy){
            foreach($hierarchy["_children"] as $key => $value){
                if(isset($value["_children"]))
                {
                    static::computeSubTotal($value);
                }
                else{
                    foreach($hierarchy["_children"] as $employee){
                         $employee_cur_compensation = $employee["cur_compensation"] ?? 0;
                        if (!isset($hierarchy["cur_compensation"])) {
                            $hierarchy["cur_compensation"] = 0;
                        } 
                        $hierarchy["cur_compensation"] += $employee_cur_compensation;
                    }
                    return $hierarchy;
                }
            }
            return $hierarchy;
        }
```

This is the function so what it does it goes to the deepest node, the deepest node is a value that does not have any _children which mean it doesn't have any sub department (the hierarchy is sorted that the sub department are always on top)

The issue I have, once it reaches the bottom it computes the cur_compensation by looping through the employees of that department and adding it on the department "cur_compensation" property.

The issue is that, it doesn't save any of my changes.

So the purpose of the function is to add up the 'cur_compensation' of each employee/sub-department.

For example ->

```
$rows = array(
array(
    'name' => "Main",
    'id' => 1,
    'parent_id' => 0,
    'cur_compensation' => 0,
    '_children' => array( 
    array(
       'name' => "Dept A",
       'id' => 2,
        'parent_id' => 1),
     ),
    array(
       'name' => "Dept B",
       'id' => 3,
       'parent_id' => 1,
       '_children' => array( 
          array(
         'name' => "Dept C",
         'cur_compensation' => 30000,
         'id' => 4,
         'parent_id' => 3),
          array(
          'name' => "Employee C",
          'cur_compensation' => 30000,
          'id' => 7,
          'parent_id' => 3
          )
     )),
     array(
     'name' => "Employee A",
     'cur_compensation' => 20000,
     'id' => 5,
     'parent_id' => 1
      ),
     array(
     'name' => "Employee B",
     'cur_compensation' => 30000,
     'id' => 6,
     'parent_id' => 1
      )
     )
 )
);
```

The result I want to get would be:

```
 $rows = array(
    array(
        'name' => "Main",
        'id' => 1,
        'parent_id' => 0,
        'cur_compensation' => 120000,
        '_children' => array( 
        array(
           'name' => "Dept A",
           'id' => 2,
           'cur_compensation' => 0,   
            'parent_id' => 1),
         ),
        array(
           'name' => "Dept B",
           'id' => 3,
           'parent_id' => 1,
           'cur_compensation' => 60000,   
           '_children' => array( 
              array(
             'name' => "Dept C",
             'cur_compensation' => 30000,
             'id' => 4,
             'parent_id' => 3),
              array(
              'name' => "Employee C",
              'cur_compensation' => 30000,
              'id' => 7,
              'parent_id' => 3
              )
         )),
         array(
         'name' => "Employee A",
         'cur_compensation' => 30000,
         'id' => 5,
         'parent_id' => 1
          ),
         array(
         'name' => "Employee B",
         'cur_compensation' => 30000,
         'id' => 6,
         'parent_id' => 1
          )
         )
     )
    );
```

So you would notice that Main and Dept B got the cur_compensation based on the _children property

Comment: One thing I see if that you are calling `static::computeSubTotal($value);` without using a return value which probably isn't correct.

Comment: what in the world do you imagine this is doing? `$employee_cur_compensation = $employee["cur_compensation"] ?? null ? $employee["cur_compensation"] : 0;`

Comment: @ChrisHaas hmm actually that's one aspect I'm looking at, since my approach is design to go to all iterations. The reason it doesn't return is because it would yield the first last node it reached.

dqhendricks yeah that was dumb code, I forgot to to replace it, it should be $employee["cur_compensation"] ?? 0

Comment: @FranzJustinBuenaventura, it is a little hard to get to your original structure (mentally for me), but I’ve approximated [here](https://3v4l.org/CuH4q) with two versions. One is return-based and one uses a ref parameter as an output. Does this align with your data? I couldn’t find a good reason to modify the array itself, so I didn’t use a bytes array. If this does align, I can post an answer, otherwise some more clarity is needed

Comment: @ChrisHaas thanks for taking your time writing this code, will update the post so it has more information what I want to achieve. So my setup right now it has Departments and sub-departments. So what I'm trying to compute is the total for each sub-department. that's why on my code I'm updating the node that doesn't have any children (which now looking at it might be the wrong approach since it will only sub-total end nodes)

Comment: @FranzJustinBuenaventura, my question is, do you _need_ to update the array in the first place? If so, that’s totally valid, but then we don’t need to return anything probably. Hopefully your edit brings more context.

Comment: @ChrisHaas yes for updating the array, it's because the Hierarchy I'm creating right now would be feed into a table that does read the properties for each child. Hopefully the edit I did make sense, let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: @FranzJustinBuenaventura, thanks for the update. It is slightly weird to both use and alter a single key such as `cur_compensation`. Not wrong, just weird. Ideally you would create a new unique key (name doesn’t matter) that doesn’t exist in your existing dataset so you can reason about things. If you can imagine a nested set of a family, summing the ages arguably makes sense, but setting the root age to 214 probably doesn’t, and instead should be `total years`. Arguably semantics, but really helps with recursion. Regardless, I’ll need to hop back on with a real computer tomorrow

Comment: @ChrisHaas Thanks, not sure what you meant by weird. If you mean why not just have something like department_subtotal or something, the table (Tabulator) I use needs to have a consistent field name for that column. So that means what is on that key will be printed on the table, in any case I don't mind using 2 fields if it makes it easier

Comment: @FranzJustinBuenaventura, I don’t mean “weird bad”, just “weird unexpected”. Generally, there’s facts and there’s calculations, and this mixes the two. In a semi-perfect world you could run the calculation on the same data as many times as you want and always receive the same data , but as it stands, your version changes the facts. Once again, not right or wrong, or (necessarily) good or bad, but when dealing with recursion especially, it helps to be very deterministic.

Comment: @FranzJustinBuenaventura, I'm looking at your source data and am confused, not sure if it is just a typo of not. But inside your outer array is an array with name Main, ID 1 which has `_children`. That makes sense. But it also has a three child arrays which hold Dept B, Employee A and Employee B, and these are not in the `_children` array. Can you confirm the data is correct and if so, what to do there?

Comment: @ChrisHaas Got it, the unexpected approach is because of a constraint unfortunately. For the source data, the Main has 4 children. Dept A, Dept B, Employee A and Employee B. 
They should be under _children of Main. Will recheck my example for correctness

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few things to make note on here - so I'm going to add comments to your existing code, then provide an example of how you could change it.

(I've formatted the code in each case)

```php
class Example {
    // filler code so that we can call
    public function process($array){
        return $this->computeSubTotal($array);
    }
    
    private function computeSubTotal($hierarchy) {
        // we're not checking whether "_children" property exists before looping on it
        foreach ($hierarchy["_children"] as $key => $value) {
            if (isset($value["_children"])) {
                // we're calling the method, but not doing anything with the return value.
                static::computeSubTotal($value);

                // we can set the original array value instead which will provide a modified copy
                // this can be resolved by uncommenting the line below
                // $hierarchy["_children"][$key] = static::computeSubTotal($value);

                // also note that if this "child" doesn't have any *grand*children
                // then we won't get an updated value due to how this is structured
                // to fix this, you could remove the else wrapping so that the code
                // below runs always
            } else {
                // double looping - we're already looping this array
                // this will cause the end value to increase exponentially
                foreach ($hierarchy["_children"] as $employee) {
                    $employee_cur_compensation = $employee["cur_compensation"] ?? 0;
                    if (!isset($hierarchy["cur_compensation"])) {
                        $hierarchy["cur_compensation"] = 0;
                    }
                    $hierarchy["cur_compensation"] += $employee_cur_compensation;
                }

                // returning whole array inside the loop is not ideal
                // we have already adjusted the main array
                // comment out this return to prevent that from happening
                return $hierarchy;
            }
        }
        return $hierarchy;
    }
}

$example = new Example;

// calling this on $rows won't give us anything back
// since $rows doesn't contain the property "_children"
$rows = $example->process($rows);

// in this case, you would want to process each array result
// only on this primary array
foreach($rows as $index => $value){
    $rows[$index] = $example->process($value);
}

echo json_encode($rows, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

Taking those comments into account, you would end up with something like this:

```php
private function computeSubTotal($hierarchy) {
    // we're not checking whether "_children" property exists before looping on it
    foreach ($hierarchy["_children"] as $key => $value) {
        if (isset($value["_children"])) {
            $hierarchy["_children"][$key] = static::computeSubTotal($value);
        }

        // double looping - we're already looping this array
        // this will cause the end value to increase exponentially
        foreach ($hierarchy["_children"] as $employee) {
            $employee_cur_compensation = $employee["cur_compensation"] ?? 0;
            if (!isset($hierarchy["cur_compensation"])) {
                $hierarchy["cur_compensation"] = 0;
            }
            $hierarchy["cur_compensation"] += $employee_cur_compensation;
        }
    }
    return $hierarchy;
}
```

That's closer but still, it's not quite correct due to the double looping.

I've made a simpler version that is hopefully easy to follow:

```php
private function computeSubTotal($hierarchy) {
    if (!isset($hierarchy["_children"])) {
        return $hierarchy;
    }

    // define this outside the loop for clarity
    if (!isset($hierarchy["cur_compensation"])) {
        $hierarchy["cur_compensation"] = 0;
    }

    foreach ($hierarchy["_children"] as $key => $value) {
        // don't need to check for "_children" property
        // as it's now handled in this function
        $updated = static::computeSubTotal($value);

        // reference the $updated array to increment
        // the "cur_compensation" field
        $hierarchy["cur_compensation"] += $updated["cur_compensation"] ?? 0;

        // update original array
        $hierarchy["_children"][$key] = $updated;
    }

    return $hierarchy;
}

// call like
foreach ($rows as $index => $value) {
    $rows[$index] = static::computeSubTotal($value);
}
```

You will still need to change how you're passing the `$rows` variable due to it now containing a "_children" property (as shown in the examples) - either pass each element or add additional logic in that function to handle that.

Comment: I think a major part of working with recursion is understanding that PHP assigns variables by value - that is, it creates a copy of that item when defining a variable e.g. looping over an array will create a copy of the original array and loop over it. This means you need to update the original value, not the new variable. I'd suggest looking into this more.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation, this is a good learning experience. For the final solution you presented, my only issue with that is how my hierarchy is structured. Because the difficulty I'm having is traversing through that hierarchy that contains like 4-5 layers of parent and child. Will try to do some proof of concept and add some additional logic so I properly handle it.

Comment: Forget about that comment, I thought you are just updating the final cur_compensation of the root (highest) node but it does update each node that it passes. I don't need to do a foreach since I just need to pass the highest node and it will traverse on all department. That solution fit like a glove on my project. Thank you so much, this works great

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass the array as a reference.
https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php

PHP passes the array to the function as a pointer, but when you try to update the array, PHP first makes a full copy of the array and updates the copy instead of the original.

Change your function signature to the following and it should be good.

```
private function computeSubTotal(&$hierarchy){
```

P.S. You are calling computeSubTotal statically, but the function is not static itself.

Comment: i don't think this is the problem. if you notice, they return the modified array as the return value. a better option than passing by reference.

Comment: I was going to call out the static thing, too, but I was surprised to learn that it isn't invalid and there's not even a warning about it. https://3v4l.org/HT1lJ. But I still agree that it is confusing and should be avoided.

Comment: I would argue that passing by reference is the better option since it will be less memory intensive that what PHP does by copying the array in each new scope.

Comment: I think that passing by reference versus returning in a recursive function is a case-by-case basis. I know I do both and it really just depends on what I'm doing, and sometimes which is easier for me to comprehend.

Comment: @CFulford i would argue that it makes the code far harder to read, and will cause more mistakes to be made by other people who don't realize the array is being modified without checking the function interiors. but you make a good point. i think the best option would be to just return the sub total as it's own value, and add the value to the array outside of the function, if that is even necessary. anyways, it's likely not the cause of the bug, is my main point.

Comment: Would it make more sense to remove the return on else and just modify the hierarchy directly? What should I change on my current approach?

Comment: @dqhendricks Good point on the readability standpoint. Guess I get paranoid about memory usage on recursive functions. I also agree that returning the subtotal as its own value and not the property of the array would make the most sense.

Comment: FYI PHP has no issue with calling non-static functions statically - only the other way around. Think of `parent::someFunction()` instead of calling a possibly overwritten function on the current class. That might make it make more sense.